Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no onnxruntime4j_jni in java.library.path: Android Studio ONNX ERROR
I am attempting to load an onnx model into android studio. I have downloaded everything and followed the website, but I cannot run the load method and causes BUILD ERROR.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no onnxruntime4j_jni in java.library.path:

here are my implementations:
implementation ("com.microsoft.onnxruntime:onnxruntime-android:1.17.1")
implementation ("com.microsoft.onnxruntime:onnxruntime-mobile:1.17.1")

and my method
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (OrtEnvironment env = OrtEnvironment.getEnvironment();
             OrtSession session = env.createSession("sklearn_model.onnx")) {
            System.out.println("Model loaded successfully!");
        } catch (OrtException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

I have tried to find files to download and implement into my libs folder, but can only find the dependency implemetations for Android on the official onnx website.

The library you're using requires a C .so file.  You don't have it in your build.  Or possibly you do have it, but not for the correct ABI.

Do you know of where i can get the correct file because i cannot find it
